# Does XGBoost Classifier Model pay attention to all X-data entries when making the prediction? Or only same indexed X-data?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

The following made up example is to resemble a Pandas Dataframe, which is storing the data I'm working with and housing my predicted values made by the XGBoost Classifier model

| X_Data | Target |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **??** |
| 2 | Cell 4 |

when calling `XGBClassifier.predict(df['X_data'])`
Does the predictor model look at both values in column `X_Data`?                            or only `value = 1` since the target predicted column is same index as `value = 1`?

I want my predictor to 'look' at several values around the target's index in `X_data`... I began to make other columns with `df["X_Data"].shift()` in case the model WAS 'looking' at same indexed data only, but didn't know if the model is looking at these data entries already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does XGBoost Classifier Model pay attention to all X-data entries when making the prediction?

No. Each row is classified separately.